# Is it possible to link a bug to a unit test?

Tags: tfs

If I create a bug in TFS, is it possible to associate it with a unit test and be notified if this bug is fixed/broken?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not exactly, but the workflow can go the other way: instead of creating a bug up-front, you can let Team Foundation Server handle the work item creation for you.  If you create a continuous integration build that runs your unit tests, you can create a bug assigned to the user who submitted the changeset if that build fails (including because the unit tests fail.)

A good article on configuring continuous integration to do this is in [MSDN Magazine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188695.aspx).

A new feature in TFS 2010 is Gated Check-in, which will prevent this failing code from getting checked-in by requiring the build and test steps to complete successfully before they get committed.

Answer (score 1):

There is, currently, no mechanism to do what you desire. You can force users to check in changes tagged with a work item, which you can then manually examine. Provided the user either alters a test class or creates a new one, and checks in with the fix, you can see whether it is done or not. But, there is no automagic "if this test is changed, alert me".

If you need some type of "change and alert" functionality, I would examine CodePlex and see if there are any tools of this type. It could be facilitated at the database layer, as well, but I am not sure what kind of monkeying that would take. I have not looked at the service endpoints for the latest TFS, so there may be a way to poll to see if there are changes.

Wish I had a better answer, but this is an interesting ASK, so I would consider going to Microsoft Connect for TFS and requesting the feature. It could be included in a future rev if enough people are interested in this feature.